# Welcome message with user first name using dialog flow and facebook messenger

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a simple chatbot, I want to have a welcome message with user first name something like this : assume the user first-name is Geofrey in facebook.

> Hey Geofrey.
>
> Welcome to Royal Hotel.

How can I achieve this in dialog flow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Facebook Graph API, to get User's basic Information,

```
try {
    let url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/${userId}?access_token=${config.FB_PAGE_TOKEN}`
    const response = await axios.get(url)
    let user = response.data
    var responseText = `Hi there ${user.first_name}, How can i help you today?`
    // Send Your response
} catch (error) {
    console.log("caught", error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome messages can be set using Messenger Profile API. You can set it using a simple API call, Dialogflow is not required. You can define the username using personalization {{user_first_name}} of greetings message. Read the documentation on how to set greetings from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/greeting/